# Javascript this keyword in recursion in prototype functions executes once and then undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have created a prototype and I have this function in it:

```
workRequests:
/**
 * Works out all requests in the queue with
 */
function workRequests() {

    /**
     * Checks if queue of requests is empty
     */
    if (this.queue.length == 0) {
        this.setDone(true);
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the next request
     */
    var request = this.queue.shift();
    request(function() {
        workRequests();
    });

},
```

Which is being called by the function `commit`

```
commit:
/**
 * Executes all requests till there are no requests left
 */
function commit() {
    console.log("committed");
    /**
     * Make sure the system is already committing all
     */
    running = true;
    this.workRequests();
},
```

The point of this is, I have an array named `queue`, it can store any functions in it. So I want to add many functions into the `queue` array and then when I call `commit()` I want it to execute all of these functions. However, I don't want it to execute all of them at once, but I want them to execute in a queue (wait till each one is done, then execute the next one).

I have used recursion to create this, but I am falling in the following problem:

when `workRequests` function gets called for the first time, everything works fine, but after inside the function it calls `workRequests()`, I will get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'queue' of undefined
```

I am no expert with javascript so I don't really understand what happens behind the scenes that makes the `this` keyword lose it's value that used to be the same in the first call of `workRequests()`.

I call the whole thing like this:

```
var reqs = new SyncRequests();
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    reqs.executeRequest(function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: 'www.google.com',
            data:  {direction: 'up' },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                callback();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
}
reqs.commit();
```

An help solving the error would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When you call a function like this, `foo()`, then `this` will refer to the global object or `undefined` (in strict mode).

Comment: You might want to set `async:false` if you want to make sure they execute one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly arrange for `this` to be set:

```
var request = this.queue.shift();
var self = this;
request(function() {
    workRequests.call(self);
});
```

Slightly simpler maybe:

```
var request = this.queue.shift();
request(workRequests.bind(this));
```

The `.bind()` method returns a function that calls *your* function such that `this` will be set to the given value.